# arduino send data in binary format(binary packets) instead of 1 and 0. sending like 00000000 and 00000001(8 bit binary)

Tags: android, arduino

private void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

```
    Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: "
                + e.getMessage();
        if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
            msg = msg
                    + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
        msg = msg + ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString()
                + " exists on server.\n\n";

        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
    }
}
```

In the above code we can send data like just "0" and "1". But want to send in 8-bits like 00000000 and 00000001. It should display in Arduino board. If press to send data 1 it should show 00000001 and 00000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
String str = "25789";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
    String binarystr = Integer.toBinaryString(i); 

    char[] buffer = new char[binarystr.length()];
    binarystr.getChars(0,binarystr.length(), buffer, 0);

    System.out.println("char array:: "+Arrays.toString(buffer));

    byte[] binaryFormat = getbyteFromString(buffer);


    for (byte b : binaryFormat) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b & 255 | 256).substring(1));
    }
```

method:

```
private byte[] getbyteFromString(char[] binarystr){
int length = binarystr.length/8;

if(binarystr.length % 8 > 0)
    length++;

int iterationCount = length ;

byte[] binaryFormat = new byte[iterationCount];
int iter = iterationCount - 1;


for(int i = binarystr.length - 1; i >=0 ;){

    byte byt = 0x0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++){

        if(i < 0)
            break;

        int b = binarystr[i] - 48;
        byt = (byte) (byt + (b << j));
        i--;
    }

    binaryFormat[iter] = byt;

    iter--;
}

return binaryFormat;
```

}

Comment: No the above solution is giving java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: Answer edited. Try now. You can also use System.arraycopy(). instead of for loop to copy bytes in new byte array.

Comment: newMessage=[49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] is showing when I debug the first array index is showing 49. but I am sending as sendData("1").So, In Arduino lcd not able to see anything.

Comment: 49 is ascii value of character '1'. if you want numerical value subtract 48. Please accept as answer if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Not able to subtract because "msgBuffer" is byte value.

Comment: Sorry for earlier comment.                                             String str = "123";
        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
        String binarystr = Integer.toBinaryString(i);